# memory protection in Remote Direct Memory Access (RDMA)

Tags: rdma

Let's say I have a process that registers a piece of RDMA-accessible memory with LOCAL WRITE permission.

Does another (local) random process has the write permission to that piece of physical memory?

Answer (score 1):

No, only queue pairs that were created with the same protection domain (PD) as the MR can access it. Since another random process cannot use your process's PD, it also cannot use your MR.